# Using a string name for an object and an assembly

Tags: vb.net, object, reflection, assemblies

I'm not great with reflection and I hope I chose the right category. I have an interesting problem. I have written a report using devexpress reports. This involves a line of code like this:

```
lxListData = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of DLL.Report.ListData)
```

ListData is report in an assembly external to the one where the above line is executed. The above line works fine and allows me to run the report.

What I've done is put all the information for this report into a table as strings, That includes the type:" DLL.Report.ListData"

What I need is to change this string name into the type used in the line of code above. I have tried:

```
Dim type1 As Type = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("DLL.Report").GetType("DLL.Report.ListData")
```

and then changing the line above to:

```
lxListData = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of type1)
```

I've tried a few other techniques that are similar. In all cases the "type1" variable is not seen as a type even though it looks like it is in the watch window.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Neil

I've done some more research and found that this line:

```
Dim type1 As Type = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("DLL.Report").GetType("DLL.Report.ListData")
```

It returns a sytem.type in the variable type1, not type DLL.Report.ListData. Within that variable are two properties: Name="ListData" and FullName="DLL.Report.ListData". I was able to use some methods that were in type1 to get the properties of DLL.Report.ListData so type1 seems to be a pointer to DLL.Report.ListData.
My problem is that I need a variable that is type DLL.Report.ListData. Is there a way to take the Fullname string and return something that is the type DLL.Report.ListData instead of "system.type"?

Comment: You've tagged this question with [tag:s] (a statistical programming language) but this looks an awful lot like Visual Basic.  Does this need to be retagged?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Done. Just a stray click on the keyboard :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how:

```
Dim list As IList = _
    Ctype(Activator.CreateInstance(GetType(List(Of )).MakeGenericType(type1)), IList)
```

Keep in mind that since you are creating this at run-time that you can't have strong-typing at compile-time. The best you can do is make this an `IList`.

The other option, if you want to work with a strongly-typed list, is to call a generic method using reflection. Work done within the method is strongly-typed.

```
Dim mi = Me.GetType().GetMethod("CreateList")
Dim gmi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(type1)
Dim list = Ctype(gmi.Invoke(Me, Nothing), IList)

Public Function CreateList(Of T) As List(Of T)
    ' Strongly-typed to `T` in here
    Return New List(Of T)()
End Function
```

Comment: Enigmativity, Thanks for the answer. I figured I'd take one method at a time. So I am trying your first method. Here are things that didn't seem to work. 1.You leave the type name after List (of ) blank. I'm not sure if you left out the type name and expected me to know what to put in. I can't really put in anything because the type is what I'm trying to create. I need to create a type variable of the type "DLL.Report.ListData". Right now all I have is pointer to that type in Type1. In any case the fact that the type name is missing causes a compile error.

Comment: I tried to put object in: List(of object). This got rid of the compile error. What happened then was, at run time, I got an error that told me that I could use MakeGenericType because Type1 is not of a generic type which it isn't :-). Sorry for any missed information on my part. I'm working to understand all this.

Comment: I'll also add that instead of using the line

Comment: :System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("DLL.Report").GetType("DLL.Report.ListData") to get a pointer type I am using

Comment: Dim Ty As Type = FindType("AllMeds.EMR.Report.MUListData").MakePointerType                   This returns a clean pointer type with the name and fullname strings that contain the name of the type.

Comment: @NeilNewton - The code `GetType(List(Of ))` is valid VB.NET without any type after the `Of`. Did you try the code verbatim?

Comment: I did try the code ver batim. I was surprised as well. I will look to see if any surrounding code is causing this.

Comment: @NeilNewton - Don't forget to use the `@` notification system.

Comment: @NeilNewton - What do you mean "I was surprised as well"?

Comment: I was surprised that it didn't accept list (of ) because I had seen it elsewhere.

Comment: @NeilNewton - I checked the code before posting. It does work correctly. Are you saying it wouldn't run at your end?

Comment: Just after I answered that last question it hit me that I might need an imported namespace for the generics. I was right. This has gotten me past my problem. thanks!!!